# Why is my variance calculation method so far off?

Tags: python, data-science

I am trying to implement a method in Python which calculates the mean and variance for a stream of integers of an unknown length:

```
def mv_online (X):
    buffer = [0]
    i = 0
    for x in X:
        if i%2==0: # level 0 always empty
            buffer[0] = (x,0)
            if buffer.count(0)==0: # add new level when buffer is full
                buffer.append(0)
        else: # combination step
            j = buffer.index(0) # find level where combination will occur
            temp = (x,0)
            for k in range (0,j):
                mu1 = buffer[k][0]
                mu2 = temp[0]
                mu = (mu1+mu2)/2
                var1 = buffer[k][1]
                var2 = temp[1]
                var = var1+var2+0.5*(mu1-mu2)*(mu1-mu2)
                temp = (mu,var)
                buffer[k]=0 # clean buffer at respective levels
            buffer[j]=temp
        i+=1
    return buffer[-1] if buffer[-1]!=0 else buffer[-2]
```

While the mean is correct, the variance is much higher as compared to the naive variance calculation, i.e. the sum over `(x_i - mean)^2 * 1/(n-1)`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The default varince function in Numpy is population variance (n in the denominator). If you need to have the sample variance (n-1 in the denominator) you need to specify ddof=1.

Check this out:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,8])

def variance_population(a):
    return np.sum(np.square(a - np.mean(a)))/(len(a))

def variance_sample(a):
    return np.sum(np.square(a - np.mean(a)))/(len(a) - 1)

print(np.var(a))
print(variance_population(a))

print(np.var(a, ddof=1))
print(variance_sample(a))
```

I am not sure where you are calculating the mean or the variance in your code though.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are taught the formal definition of variance, an alternative definition is "the mean of the square minus the square of the mean".

So as you are iterating through the numbers, you just need to keep trace of count, sum, and sum of squares.  You can then easily calculate the variance and the standard deviation using these three values.  For the alternative standard deviation, multiply your variance by `count / (count - 1)`.